# Getting recent user likes in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a site where user like products, i need for each product to show the list of up to 10 users who recently liked the product **ordered by created at desc** and their avatars. I am trying to find an efficient way to do that, note that a product can have 1000's of likes, and to be efficient **I only want to show the last 10 likes.**

I have two tables

products

```
id, title, ....
```

likes

```
id, user_id, product_id, created_at
```

I would like to get up to 10 user ids who liked the product recently. from there I will do another query on the user ids to get their names and avatars, but how do I make this first query to get the user ids for each product ?

so result should be

```
product_id, liked by
1           12,23,45,67
2           13,4,5
3           1

etc
```

Comment: I'm worried about expending more effort on the answer than has been expended on the question.

Comment: OK, I will try to edit

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running this query:

```
SELECT p.id AS product_id, u.username, u.avatar, u.id AS user_id FROM products AS p 
LEFT JOIN likes AS l ON l.produc_id = p.product_id
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.id = l.user_id
WHERE p.id = {PRODUCT_ID} -- If you want it for a single product
ORDER BY l.created_at DESC
LIMIT 10
```

This will return you the list of 10 usernames and their avatars for a product all in one query.

You might need to adjust this query as you have not provided detailed explanation of your table and their relations.

Edit:

adding another sql example as per request:

```
SELECT l.product_id, p.name AS product_name, GROUP_CONCAT(l.user_id) AS listOfUsers, GROUP_CONCAT(u.username) AS username, GROUP_CONCAT(u.avatar) AS avatars  FROM likes AS l
LEFT JOIN products AS p ON p.id = l.product_id
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.id = l.user_id
WHERE l.product_id IN(1,2,3)
ORDER BY l.created_at DESC
LIMIT 10
```

This should return something like

```
product_id | listOfUsers | usernames          | avatars
1          |  1,2,3      |  test1,test2,test3 |  img1, img2, img3
2          |  4,5,6      |  test4,test5,test6 |  img4, img5, img6
```

Edit #2:

I think this is the query you were looking for:

```
SELECT p.id, GROUP_CONCAT(l.user_id) As userList, GROUP_CONCAT(l.username) AS usernameList, GROUP_CONCAT(l.avatar) AS avatarList
FROM products AS p
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT l.product_id, l.user_id, u.username, u.avatar
    FROM likes AS l
    LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.id = l.user_id
    ORDER BY l.created_at DESC 
    LIMIT 10
) 
AS l ON l.product_id = p.id
WHERE p.id IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: OK, thx, a good start, but how do I make it return something like in my example where product id is IN a list of product ids and each product has the list of 10 recent likes in one row

Comment: I can try but wouldn't this LIMIT the number of lines the top select will match and not the number of users per product ?

Comment: I think it will do just what you said, but I'm not sure on how to limit the number of users per product without creating sub queries inside the joins which can slow down your sites load time if not written properly

Comment: so this doesn't work, the limit on the inner select doesn't limit the number of users per product, it seems like it's limiting the whole join, I have test data where the first 60 products have 20000 votes from random users, each product has about 70-80 votes, when I LIMIT 10 I many products don't have votes at all, when I put 100 more have more votes and when I put 1000 many have much more than votes.

Comment: yes just tested edit #2, the LIMIT controls how many total votes I can see for all the products together